# Android Studio 3.1.1 - unable to add module (import gradle project)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, import, module, crash

Android Studio 3.1.1. New module -> Import gradle project, after I select project to import and confirm, IDE crashes with exception:

> Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file:///home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseJobTest/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=26}}(1416c50); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file:///home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseJobTest/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=26}}(665cfacf)
>   invalidated at: see attachment
>   com.intellij.psi.PsiInvalidElementAccessException: Element: class org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file:///home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseJobTest/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=26}}(1416c50); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file:///home/michal/AndroidStudioProjects/FirebaseJobTest/settings.gradle, content=VirtualFileContent{size=26}}(665cfacf)
>   invalidated at: see attachment
>       at com.intellij.psi.util.PsiUtilCore.ensureValid(PsiUtilCore.java:502)

Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 22):

I was facing the same issue, seems like IDE issue, try manually adding

`include ':app', ':your_module_name'`

in settings.gradle and sync gradle, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I have already reported bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77939622 you can confirm issue there